# How do I prove that the multiplicative identity of a field is unique in a different way?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook Linear Algebra by Friedberg/Insel/Spence, it says that the uniqueness of the multiplicative inverse in a field is a consequence of Theorem C.1 (Cancellation Laws).

But my proof does not use cancellation:

> Suppose that $1'$ in $F$ satisfies $1'a = a$ for all a in $F$.
>
> Choose $a = 1$. Then $1' \cdot 1 = 1$.
>
> By (F3), $1a = a$ for all $a$ in $F$. Choose $a = 1'$. Then $1 \cdot
> > 1' = 1'$.
>
> By (F1), it follows that $1' = 1 \cdot 1' = 1' \cdot 1 = 1$. So the multiplicative identity is unique.

So how do I prove that the multiplicative identity is unique using Theorem C.1 (Cancellation Laws)?

[image: Screenshot of textbook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original proof is perfectly valid. But if you insist on using a cancellation law to prove that if $1,1'$ are both multiplicative identities then $1=1'$, just write $1\times 1=1=1'\times 1$, and then cancel the $1$ from the right to obtain $1=1'$. Contrary to your original proof this does use $1\neq0$; this is an axiom of fields.

Comment: Thank you professor.

Here is another way I though of before.

Suppose that 1' in F satisfies that 1' a = a for each a in F.

Since 1 a = a for each a in F,

we have 1' a = 1 a for each a in F.

If a ≠ 0,

then cancel the a from the right to obtain 1' = 1.

What if a = 0?

How to prove that 1 ' = 1 when a = 0 ?

Because a ≠ 0 in cancellation laws.

This confused me.

Comment: @user9418: Your method gives a separate proof for each $a$, except for $a=0$ where you don't get a proof. But you only need _one_ proof, so you can do without $a=0$, as long as there is some $a\neq0$ left. There certainly is such an $a$, for instance $1\neq0$ is assured. In fact if you take $a=1$, you get the proof I mentioned.

Comment: Indeed,

as you mentioned 1 ≠ 0 which can be found in F3.

If a = 1,

the better way you gave solved the proof.

I just don't understand what is the meaning of "a = 0 and still 1' = 1".

By F3, 

1 a = a for ALL a in F.
1' a = a for ALL a in F.

So 0 must satisfies F3,

but it seems that a proof needs not to show 1' = 1 when a = 0.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't understand you difficulty. The statement to prove is $1=1'$, and it does not involve any value $a$. It is just F3 that mentions $a$, if you want to use F3 in your proof (which is your free choice), then you must do so for some value of $a$. But if you would choose $a=0$ it would not be possible to conclude (you wouldn't get anything false, just not sufficient to conclude $1=1'$); so that choice is to be avoided. But there remain other choices that _will_ allow you to conclude, so you do that: let $a$ be any nonzero element. There is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is my doubt about that difficulty inappropriate for studying mathematics?

Comment: Doubt is always appropriate.

Comment: In order to figure out these proofs I failed to comprehend. Then I try to read book "How to prove it" by Velleman. Finally, the more I learn about "proof by contradiction", the more I can follow the explanation you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a \neq 0$ in the field. Then you know that it has at least one inverse, i.e. an element $b_1$ such that $ab_1=b_1 a=1$. Suppose you have another element with this property denoted by $b_2$. Then $ab_1=ab_2=1$ and $a \neq 0$. So your theorem implies $b_1=b_2$ and there is only one such element after all.

Comment: I think you misread the question. This is not about the uniqueness of multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Oh right, I was too quick there. By now of course the correct proof is given.